# how to disable form elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, disabled-control

I have multiple form elements on a page and I have a next button for each form. I fill a form and click on next button to scroll to next form. I want that after filling up a form when user clicks next button it should disable all elements of previous elements.

**What I tried:**
I assigned unique `id` to all forms and tried following

```
$('form #firstFrm').find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

But it did not do anyything.

```
$("#firstFrm> input").attr("disabled", true);
```

but not effect.

```
$("#firstFrm :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

for this instead of disabling elements under `form` with `id` **firstFrm** it disable elements of all form.

how to disable elements of particular form only.

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="" method="post">      
    <fieldset class="sectionwrap">
        <legend style="padding-right: 425px;">User Details</legend>
        <fieldset class="column" style= "width: 500px;margin-top: 10px;">
            <div id="firstFrm">
                <table style="padding-right: 20px; float: left"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td id="targetTD">
                            Username : <input id="email" type="email" name="email"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password : <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            password : <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" class="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

### Solution

I created `div` under `form` and put all elements in that `div` and instead of disabling elements under `form` I disabled elements under `div`. This worked fine.

Comment: Try with `prop` as in `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: disabled all elements of all forms.

Comment: how does your HTML markup look like?

Comment: above is my html code that worked

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$( '#firstFrm input' ).attr ( 'disabled', true );
```

Comment: it is also disabling elements of all form

Comment: You mean all elements on all forms get disabled? If that's the case, then you have some HTML markup issues.

Comment: I don't think so coz I checked opening and closing of all forms and all are opened and closes properly which I think should not let jquery to jump into another form and modify it.

Comment: Check your markup in a validator, or post it here so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bit lenghty but you can try that as soon as the user goes to next input type you can disable the above elment using its id i.e.

```
{ $( '#input' ).attr ( 'disabled', true ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('form #firstFrm')` will look for a form with `id="firstForm"` which is inside another `<form>` element

```
<form>
    <div>
        <form id="firstForm"></form>
    </div>
</form>
```

`$("#firstFrm > input")` will get only the direct `<input/>` children of a form

```
<form>
    <input />     // this is matched
    <div>
        <input/>  // this is not matched
    </div>
</form>
```

To get all the inputs try this:

```
$("input", $("#formId")).attr("disabled", true)
```

or

```
$("#formId input").attr("disabled", true)
```